# Dual booted Win10 with Ubuntu 14.04, always boots to Ubuntu, and can't switch back

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I've had Ubuntu on my laptop for the longest of time and I've loved it ever since. But then I decided to get Windows 10, and completely forgot about dual booting, however, after getting Windows 10, I dual booted it with Ubuntu again, now for some reason, it always boots to Ubuntu and never even gives me a choice, I need help, this is frustrating :/.

Gparted screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Check with `Gparted` how do the partitions look and edit the post with that info.

Comment: If you are using Windows 10, you must make sure fast start up or always on hibernation is off. And/or turn off all hibernation settings including low battery. Only then can grub2's os-prober find the Windows boot files to know what partition to boot Windows from. And Windows may turn fast start back on with updates. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Grub will not boot hibernated Windows. You may have to temporarily install a Windows boot loader to boot Windows to turn off fast start up. Then reinstall grub & run `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

Four things to do:

1. 'sudo nano /etc/default/grub' to edit the grub configuration
2. Find the line 'GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true' and change the 'true' to 'false'
3. Ctrl + x to save and Y
4. 'sudo update-grub && sudo reboot'

All the best

Comment: Thanks will give it a try and respond with feedback!

EDIT: Nope, don't see the line "GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true"

Comment: If you're not comfortable with nano, you can use gedit or any other editor.

Comment: https://s21.postimg.org/le4eicsyf/Screenshot_from_2016_11_16_20_35_37.png

Comment: Okay, since it's not there, you can add the line below GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" "

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried boot-repair, it worked for me.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair